# Google Analytics loses tracking after a few minutes

Tags: android, ios, session, google-analytics

I set up Google Analytics for both iOS and Android as described in both tutorials ([Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/) & [iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/)).

Here's my `analytics.xml` for Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxx-y</string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">-1</integer>
</resources>
```

In Android I set up the `EasyTracker` object in my `Activity#onStart()` as:

```
EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
```

And in iOS, in my AppDelegate:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:kTrackingId];
```

And my `ViewController#viewDidLoad` that extends `GAITrackedViewController`:

```
self.screenName = @"My ViewController";
```

I can see the value of 1 (or 2, if I'm testing with both devices) in the GA's website (Reporting > Real-Time Session), specifically in this part:

[image: GA's screenshot]

The problem is that both devices, with both screens active, only maintains that count in GA's website for a few minutes, even though I'm not closing the app or putting them to sleep.
What's happening? Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en

Active Visitor Metrics

In Real-Time, a user is active if he or she has triggered an event or pageview within the past 5 minutes. Note that this is different from standard reports in which a session is defined by a 30 minute window.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Glauco. So there is no way I can measure the number of people currently listening to my music inside my app, right?

Comment: Maybe you can use some timer to trigger an event each 5 minutes.